# Trying to bind a callback function on click of JQuery using Highcharts and GWT

Tags: javascript, jquery, gwt, highcharts

I am using highcharts 3.0.8 and Jquery 1.10.0.

I am trying to do something on click of data points on the pie chart. The code is working just fine when I use it in JSFiddle.

Here is the link : http://jsfiddle.net/Cq98n/2/

***But when I use the same thing in GWT using the same 2 Javascripts, it is throwing me the below error*** in developer tool (firebug) and click function is not delegated.

```
TypeError: handleObj.handler.apply is not a function

.apply( matched.elem, args );

jquery-1.10.0.js (line 5107)
```

**NOTE:** Only click functions are not getting delegated. When I use some other function for tooltip, it is working just fine. I am able to render all kinds of charts, but cannot delgate the click event.

*Can somebody explain this anomaly*.

It might not be related to GWT as I think it is Javascript or rather JQuery issue.

Comment: Have you tried to use GWT wrapper, prepared by moxie group ? http://www.moxiegroup.com/moxieapps/gwt-highcharts/

Comment: I am using that only to build Json string on the server side by using another 3rd party tool called jackson. Then passing the built json string to the high charts